# Why was Judah named that: doesn't the name hurt Rachel?

Tags: names, shevatim-12-tribes, vayeitzei, imahot-matriarch-mothers

According to [Rashi (Genesis 29:35)](http://chabad.org/8224#showrashi=true&v=35), Leah thanks Hashem after having Yehuda, because she received more than her lot, and that is why he's called Yehuda.

This Rashi always bothered me. If I sue my friend Jim and I make $10 million, isn't it wrong of me to build a $10mil mansion and call the house "Jim"? I would never make any mention of it because I took something from **Jim**.  Isn't this rubbing it in? Should she not have instead been quiet to herself and counted her blessings internally? And perhaps even felt bad that she took a child from Rachel?

Answer (score 4):

Your analogy is incorrect as it does not apply to what happened to Leah. Leah did not attempt to "take away" a son from Rachel and it was thanks to Hashem who had done this. Rav Hirsch points out that with each of the three previous sons she recognized an increasing connection to her husband. In fact, Rav Hirsch says

> It is accordingly, highly significant that at Levi, it is not she, but
>   he who expresses this in giving the baby its name. ... so that, when
>   the fourth son was born, Yehudah, she no longer had to welcome it as a
>   means of progress in her husband's love towards her, which she now
>   fully possessed, but could simply enjoy her baby purely for its own
>   sake. She accordingly pronounced the words of a happy mother "This
>   time I can thank Hashem, just for His gift itself" and called the
>   child Yehudah.

Thus we see it was not taken away from Rachel, but an acknowledgement of the goodness of Hashem.

Additionally, she could have considered him the fourth child of the six that she had been alloted. That is, the maidservants had not yet been given to Yaakov as wives and might not be part of the count. According to Rashi, who counts all four, Rachel could also have had four and each of the maidservants two. Thus, the acknowledgement did not "take away" from Rachel.

Indeed, When her final child was born (Dinah), Leah prayed that it be a girl and that Rachel have a boy (Yosef). The medrash says that originally, Dinah was supposed to be another boy and Leah's prayer changed the event so that she had a girl and Rachel could have two boys.

Thanks to @DanF for pointing out that Rachel did not feel as the analogy might have it either.

> Within the "mix" keep in mind that when the Torah says that she was
>   "jealous" of Leah, it was a "positive" jealousy (see Rash"i on that
>   verse). She was jealous that G-d answered Leah's prayers, and realized
>   that she had to try harder. She wasn't hurt that Leah had all those
>   children. If anything, we see how Rachel always tried to appease her
>   older sister, even in a situation where, perhaps, Leah was acting
>   "mean". In short, to say or imply that Le'ah was rubbing it in seems
>   incorrect. – DanF

Comment: ty. However, Rashi says she was happy because she received  more than her chalk. My question is on Rashi

Comment: @EdRosenberg I added a reference to why even according to Rashi the analogy is incorrect.

Comment: rashi says she was prasing g-d because she got more then her share. What did he mean by that. You seem to be explaining how she didn't at this point  "take away" necessarily but Rashi says she did

Comment: @EdRosenberg I was saying that Rashi said that she got "more than her share" but that it does not necessarily mean that she "took away" from Rachel. Nor does the phrase mean that it was anything other than acknoeledging the goodness of Hashem. Nor is it like the analogy of suing a friend and throwing it in his face.

Comment: Within the "mix" keep in mind that when the Torah says that she was "jealous" of Leah, it was a "positive" jealousy (see Rash"i on that verse). She was jealous that G-d answered Leah's prayers, and realized that she had to try harder. She wasn't hurt that Leah had all those children. If anything, we see how Rachel always tried to appease her older sister, even in a situation where, perhaps, Leah was acting "mean". In short, to say or imply that Le'ah was rubbing it in seems incorrect.

Comment: @Danf agreed - it was good jealousy. That is why I always had this question on the rashi that seems to say she called him Yehuda because she got more then her  share. Im not sure I agree with at sabbahillel yet -

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an answer can be brought courtesy of the Ksav Sofer.

The Gemara in [Brachos 7:](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.7b.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) states that Leah was the first person in the world to give thanks. On the surface this is hard to understand, especially since there were a number of righteous people that had lived virtuous lives (Avraham, Sarah, Yitzchak, Rivka and Yaakov)?! Yet, the [Ksav Sofer](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14083&st=&pgnum=148&hilite=) points out that whilst they too thanked Hashem, their thanks was for open miracles. Leah was the first person to show gratitude over a ‘natural’ experience – i.e. the act of having four children. Therefore, Leah introduced us to the fact that one must give thanks even for the everyday things that go on around us.

As such, she wasn't 'rubbing it in', it was rather a declaration of genuine thanks to Hashem.

Comment: My torah which may be of interest to you about Leah. Why was Rachel complaining and jealous. She should do the good deeds herself. And what exactly where the good deeds of Leah. That she gave her violets for her husband. That she was crying about marrying esau, that was all in the past. No it was something else entirely which rachel couldnt copy and be only jealous of.

Comment: I hear. Although, it is worth noting the Lekach Tov, Bereishis 29:31 that says because Leah was aggrieved (i.e. feeling second-rate, unloved) she had the largest share of kids, otherwise Yaakov would have divorced her(!) - https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Lekach_Tov%2C_Genesis.29.31.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: I can do better than that. Look at the baal haturim on leah was crying. That is how a wife has to be..Those are her good deeds. Rachel's temperament couldnt do that.

Comment: Yikes! Good spot!

Comment: Thanks you have heard nothing yet! I make them every week. I am told I should print them. But this one I consider excellent.